# JasperReports on new tab

Tags: java, servlets, jasper-reports

I'm a newbie here and I would like to consult something regarding JasperReports and servlets.

I have a form called appform.jsp which is an application page. 
What I want to achieve is that when I click the Submit button of the application page, a new tab will open then a PDF file will be displayed.
The submit button calls the sevlet that will generate the pdf then the PDF will be displayed in a new tab.

I wonder if this line is correct
    `<input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="validateForm(); openinnewtab('<%=request.getContextPath()+"/readFields"%>')" >`

validateForm() is just a javascript checker for empty fields, readFields is my servlet and my form's onsubmit tag is on return false;

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

give `target="_blank"` in the form tag. some browsers open a page some a tag . you can also try `target="_new"` using this you can easily open new tab

Comment: I am able to print the PDF file but the problem is that the fields' values in the file are all null :(

Comment: Since you can able to print the PDF file, just showing null, it means that the problem is in the jrxml itself. Post the related jrxml.